# Mergesort with pytable

Tags: mergesort, pytables, numexpr

I have two large tables (not fiting in memory) with an id, I'd like to merge (join).

Is there a way to do that fastly with pytables ? i thank about full-indexing the two tables and using itersorted with this kind of algorithm : http://en.literateprograms.org/Merge_sort_%28Python%29 .

But it may be possible to take advantage of the numexp library to do that faster ?

Thx.